# Swift: Error - Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type using guard let

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

While working with guard let statement for functional call, it showing error. I don't want to use if let condition as there will be multiple condition used after that. Please let me know what I am doing wrong or something that needs to be changed.

```
  var sampleString: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let sample = self.createSampleCall(firstSampleName: sampleString) else {
            print("sample is nil"); return
        }        
    }

    func createSampleCall(firstSampleName: String) -> String {
        print(firstSampleName)
        return firstSampleName
    }
```

Comment: `createSampleCall` does **not** return an optional so it can't be `nil`. That's what the error message says. Remove `guard` and `else { ... }`.

Comment: Also, do you want to check the nil condition for sampleString? If so, its better you make it optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Guard statment or 'if let' statment is used only for optinal values
```

if you observe your method returns `String` not  `String?` (Optional String)

That's why it is showing error

Hope it is clear to you